# MongoDB Query Conversion to PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

Hey everyone I am trying to replicate this query in `PHP` using `MongoClient`.

```
db.rss.find({'channel__list.items.item.sd:ids.sd:id.sd:id': 
                       '6a81cc65- fc97-40d2-9c95-74cbfd25626e'})
```

Can someone help me out with this issue? I am not exactly sure how to access elements inside of elements using the find command on `MongoClient`, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this helps
http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

```
$collection->find(array('channel__list.items.item.sd:ids.sd:id.sd:id' => '6a81cc65- fc97-40d2-9c95-74cbfd25626e'));
```

Is the literal interpretation, although you will need to define $collection

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb:///tmp/mongodb-20000.sock"); // file socket, but can use URL socket
$collection = $m->selectCollection("foo", "bar.baz"); // choses DB & collection
```

You can also define $collection separately to the DB Using

```
$collection = $m->selectDB("foo")->selectCollection("bar.baz"); // chained
// or
$m->selectDB("foo"); // select DB (maybe in separate method)
$collection = $m->selectCollection("bar.baz"); // (then set collection)
```

Hope this Helps

Comment: I will give the first solution a try, but I believe it's elements inside of elements.

Comment: Yep, that doesn't work here is an example of the output of that query you will see the elements inside of elements.

Comment: Actually it worked! It turns out I was using the wrong database. I figured it was because of the .'s meaning inside of other elements but that works! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: ;) glad to be of help